# ELK containers are unable to connect on different nodes when firewall is running

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, docker-swarm

I have a ELK docker swarm setup running across 4 different hosts. I am able to ping the containers which are on different host but when I try to run curl commands it is not connecting `curl http://elastic:9200`. Logstash and kibana applications are unable to connect to elasticsearch containers (3 node es cluster) which are on different hosts. I have opened all the ports mentioned in docker swarm documentation across all hosts https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#the-ip-address-of-the-manager-machine but no luck. After stopping firewall on all hosts, LS/Kibana are able to connect to elasticsearch.

Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://es-proxy:9200/

Has anyone experienced this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Why localhost? It should be service name instead I think. Is there extra message you might put except for the last paragragh?

Comment: I am not using localhost. I am using http://es-proxy:9200/ loadbalancer. I believe I posted the wrong error message. I'll update that. Essentially, it just keeps throwing an error saying it can't connect.

Comment: Elasticsearch needs multiple ports too. Did you open them already?

Comment: Yes, I have opened elasticsearch ports as well. Ports 9200 and 9300.

Comment: As you said, firewall forwarding policy is the most likely issue. So I assume you could add the information about how you open ports. That might help a lot~

Comment: I opened the ports using the following commands:
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9200/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9300/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding my docker network interface into a trusted zone.

https://success.docker.com/article/firewalld-problems-with-container-to-container-network-communications

Lastly, I added my docker subnet as a trusted source.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=subnet/range
```